# Cannot connect cyber ops workstation vm to internet

Tags: virtual-machine

My stuff include:
mac os with Mojave OS, 
vmware Fusion 11, 
cyberops workstation as virtual machine.

After installing cyberops vm using vmware fusion 11, I tried to connect the vm to the internet but it doesn't work. I am using wifi on my mac to connect the internet ant it works fine. please help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Open the terminal and type in

```
$ sudo systemctl start dhcpcd@ens33.service
$ sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd@ens33.service
```

where `ens33` stands for the name of your NIC (you can find the name using the `ip address` command. If the name is different in your setup you have to change it in the command to yours)